# Wifi connection not showing up

Tags: windows-10

My wifi was working last night. I put my PC on standby then when I go to use it today, the wifi connection is not there on the PC but is there on my phone. This has happed with windows 7 before.

Rebooting, disable/enabling the adapter, and using the troubleshooter fixes nothing. Note that two wifi connections do show up but these are not for my network.

I uninstalled tunnelbear and its driver, windows updates and .net frameworks but still no luck.

Comment: Please add more detail and show us you have tried researching the issue and as to what you have done already to try and resolve it: did you try troubleshooting? enabling disabling adapter? etc. Also show us more detail about the issue: what does the connection tray icon show? is the adapter on? what is your adapter? Perhaps googling internet resolution fixes, because there are tons of guides online. We are not going to hold you hand every part of the way. There are many things that could be the cause for no connection.

Comment: @El8tedN8te Ive tried everything youve said already. The connection tray shows two wifi networks but these are not the right ones.

Comment: Okay, I will revoke my downvote iff you edit your post because you were not clear what you meant by connection showing up: SSIDs, or no WiFi at all. Any normal person would have interpreted by your post that you had no WiFi at all, _not_ that an SSID is missing; questions should be detailed and thorough; with this cleared up, it is far less broad but still broad. Context is everthing. Also please add the adapter's model please.

Answer (score 1):

I reset my router now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to connect to the SSID manually and see if that works.

1. Right click the wireless tray icon on the taskbar → Select **Open Network and Sharing Center**
2. Click **Set up a new connection or network**
3. Choose **Manually connect to a wireless network** and Next.
4. Type in the SSID *exactly* as broadcasted from the router (or in your case, as you see it on your phone). Select from the drop down "WPA2-Personal" (this is often the case for home/small-office routers). Enter the security key aka the password for that connection. Toggle "**Start this connection automatically**". Now you may have to go back to toggle "**Connect even if the network is not broadcasting**" on depending on if it connects after pressing Next, but keep it off. (If your phone can see it, there is a high chance you don't have to toggle it on).
5. If prompted with "A network called ... already exits" select "Use the existing network"

If this somehow fail let's ensure some settings are correct in your wireless adapter:

1. Right click the wireless tray icon on the taskbar → Select **Open Network and Sharing Center**
2. Click **Change adapter settings**
3. Right click the WiFi or wireless adapter (it should show a wireless network symbol) → Choose **Properties** from the context menu → Click **Configure** → Open the **Advanced** tab
4. Locate a setting that is similiar to "Wireless Mode" among the individual settings (you may have to look around not all adapter settings are the same). Ensure this setting is set to "802.11b/g/n" so it can access all sorts. If you see a settings that mention "Channels" set these to Auto. Auto is the best setting for all of these settings if it is available (in most cases).